# Siddhi: Add query id to results of query

Tags: siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I have multiple queries that output results to the same output stream.

Looking at the query result in the output stream, I want to tie back the result to the query that triggered the result.

Is there a way for me to enrich a query result with the id/name of the query that triggered the output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert that as a constant event attribute to the stream. Please refer below

```
from inputStream
select "query1" as queryName, attr1, attr2
insert into mergingStream;
```